# Safe built-in inside for loop Django CKEditor

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor with Django and when i need show some RTF code in my template, usually, I use the safe built in filter (autoscape).

Example:

```
<p class="card-text">{{ questao.enunciado|safe }}</p>
```

But, how to use safe built-in inside a for loop?

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        <strong>{{ field.label_tag }}</strong>
        {{ field|safe }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
            <p class="help">{{ field.help_text }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This way above is not working for me, and in the template it ends up showing me HTML codes in text format.

Answer (score 1):

You need not use the safe for the field.

Try:

```
{% for field in form %}
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
    {% if field.help_text %}
    <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Also refer [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields)

Answer (score 0):

You are applying `safe` filter to the wrong value. You have to apply it to `field.label` or `field.help_text` instead, e.g.:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label|safe }}</label>
        {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
            <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```